# How do I concatenate a string to all the members inside a comma seperated list in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, relational-database

For example my comma separated string looks like

```
Declare @lists nvarchar(max) = N'EmailID , PhoneNumber , Profession'
```

I want to append a string like 'aliasName.' to all the members such that the list should look like

```
@lists = N'aliasName.EmailID , aliasName.PhoneNumber , aliasName.Profession'
```

Comment: Instead of forcing in a table alias which indicates this is being used a parameter and then being executed you should consider using a string splitter instead so you can properly parameterize your queries and avoid a visit from little bobby tables. http://bobby-tables.com/ Here is an excellent article about some ways you can split strings in sql server. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @lists nvarchar(max) = N'EmailID , PhoneNumber , Profession'
SET @lists = N'aliasName.' + replace(@lists,' , ', ' , aliasName.')
SELECT @lists
```

That should give you the following result:

```
 aliasName.EmailID , aliasName.PhoneNumber , aliasName.Profession
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
DECLARE @lists NVARCHAR(100)=N'EmailID , PhoneNumber , Profession';
DECLARE @AliasName NVARCHAR(100)=N'aliasName.';
SET @lists = @AliasName +  REPLACE(REPLACE(@lists,' ',''),',',' , ' + @AliasName);
SELECT @lists;
```